# Make widgets as large as scrollable frames with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to python, so bear with me. 
I've looked everywhere but I can't find a solution to my problem. 

I'm trying to make a GUI downloader using python 3 and tkinter and I need to add a scrollbar to the frame with the downloaded files. I was able to accomplish that, but the only problem is I can't seem to make the widgets inside the scrollable frame fill the entire length of it.
[Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Zej.png)

This is the code I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
window=Tk()
window.geometry("800x500")
frame=Frame(window)
frame.pack(fill="both",expand=True)


headerframe=Frame(frame,bg="black")
container=Frame(frame)

button=Button(headerframe,text="This is an example",bg="blue",fg="white",padx=10,pady=10)
button.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew",padx=10,pady=10)
headerframe.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

headerframe.pack(fill="x")
canvas = Canvas(container)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
container.pack(fill="both",expand=True)
scrollable_frame.bind(
"<Configure>",
lambda e: canvas.configure(
scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
)
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame2=Frame(scrollable_frame, bg="black")
frame2.pack(fill="both",expand=True)



fileframe=Frame(scrollable_frame,bg="orange")


label=Label(fileframe, text="1", bg="orange")
label.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2)

title=Label(fileframe,text="filename",padx=5,bg="orange",anchor="w")
title.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew")

progress=Progressbar(fileframe)
progress['value']=0
progress.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")

labelPercentage=Label(fileframe,text="0 %",padx="5",anchor="w",bg="orange",fg="white")
labelPercentage.grid(row=0,column=2)
labelsize=Label(fileframe,text="0 KB",padx="5",anchor="w",bg="orange",fg="white")
labelsize.grid(row=1,column=2)

fileframe.pack(fill="x")
fileframe.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
window.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me? I've read there's a difference between the scrollable area and the scrollable frame, and I'm very confused. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that `scrollable_frame` should fill the width of the canvas?

Comment: I thought my scrollable_frame already filled the width of the canvas? :/ I want the widgets I put inside the scrollable_frame to fill the width of the canvas, if that makes sense.

Comment: No, the `scrollabe_frame` does not fill the width.  You can set the background color of the canvas to verify it.  Or add `width=600` in `create_window(...)` to see the effect.

Comment: Oh, okay. Then how can I make it fill the width of the canvas? Thank you so much for replying :)

Comment: `win = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")` and then `canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.itemconfig(win, width=e.width))`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!